# i am trying to merge two datatable into one and display in the gridview but the datatable values display in different rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

```
            var xmlFilePath3 = Server.MapPath("t.xml");//Location of the XML file.
            DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
            ds4.ReadXml(xmlFilePath3);
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2 = ds4.Tables[0];
            DataTable dtamnt = new DataTable();
            dtamnt = ds4.Tables[2];
            dt2.Merge(dtamnt);
            GridView4.DataSource = dt2;
            GridView4.DataBind();
```

I am merging two datatables here and displaying values in the gridview.But in the gridview the second datatable values comes in different row not in the same row as the first datatable.How to put it in the same row.Thanks in advance

Comment: Obviously merge is working like this, if you want to be on same row try common column and group by

Comment: there is a common column actually but still it would not show up in the same row

Comment: You need a custom xml parser.  The depth of the data in the xml is too deep to  get all data in a single datatable.  The first tag in the xml is the Dataset name.  The 2nd tag is the DataTable(s) names.  The 3rd tag is the column names.  Then the next tag is the rows in the DataTable.  If you have more tags multiple tables are created which are very difficult to merge.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq it is very easy

```
 var results = from table1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                     join table2 in dtamnt.AsEnumerable() on (int)table1["common column"] equals (int)table2["common column"]
                     select new
                     {

                         ColX = (int)table1["ColX"],
                         ColY = (int)table1["ColY"],
                         ColZ = (int)table2["ColZ"],
                         ....
                        .....
                     };
```

above code helps you to make it working.